# dispatchGroup.notify(queue: inheriting QOS from the current context

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

Is there a way to dispatchGroup.notify(queue: inheriting QOS from the current context? (assuming there IS qos metainfo that's dragged through all the contexts to begin with)
The documentation on .unspecified seems terse: at least I failed to grasp it.

UPD20220810 Explore structured concurrency in Swift WWDC2021
explores the topic for newer APIs that postdate gcd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With, [`notify(qos:flags:queue:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/2016066-notify), you can specify [`.inheritQoS`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitemflags/1780749-inheritqos):

```swift
group.notify(flags: .inheritQoS, queue: queue) {
    ... 
}
```